# Remove unwanted rows from dataset in SQL

Tags: sql

Below is a billing list that shows a credit on an account for TestProcedure 880.0200
First the test is added (NEW Action) then the charge is removed (DEL ACTION). I would like to remove both entries in the ledger so it only shows what is actually being charged.

My goals is to say: IF "DEL" ACTION is present, remove the "DEL" ACTION  entry ROW along with the corresponding Test Procedure code "NEW" ACTION Entry ROW.

Thoughts?

```
VisitID RequisitionID   DateTime    SeqID   Type    TestProcedure   Action  BillCount   Charge  
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 1   L   109.0200    NEW 1   83.33   
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 2   L   300.0500    NEW 1   0.00    
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 3   L   880.0200    NEW 1   19.70   
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 4   L   880.0200    DEL -1  -19.70  
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 5   L   310.5200    ADD 1   66.67
```

OUTPUT would look like this:

```
VisitID RequisitionID   DateTime    SeqID   Type    TestProcedure   Action  BillCount   Charge
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 1   L   109.0200    NEW 1   83.33
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 2   L   300.0500    NEW 1   0.00
G201    45  2022-02-14 00:00:00.000 5   L   310.5200    ADD 1   66.67
```

Comment: What would have been the result if there were two NEW rows with 19.70? Should both been deleted, or just one (which one)?

Comment: Please TAG your specific RDBMS

Comment: Do you require a query to return the output above or delete rows from the source table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at sample data you posted, it looks as if you want to remove (from the result of a `select` statement) rows whose summary of `billcount` and `charge` column is `0` per `testprocedure`. In other words, condition you mentioned (DEL and NEW `action`) can be "simplified" to pure mathematics.

If that's so, see if this helps.

Sample data (disregard Oracle syntax; you already have data in your table, you won't type this):

```
SQL> with test (testprocedure, action, billcount, charge) as
  2    (select '109.0200', 'NEW',  1,  83.33 from dual union all
  3     select '300.0500', 'NEW',  1,   0.00 from dual union all
  4     select '880.0200', 'NEW',  1,  19.70 from dual union all
  5     select '880.0200', 'DEL', -1, -19.70 from dual union all
  6     select '310.5200', 'ADD',  1,  66.67 from dual
  7    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  select *
  9  from test a
 10  where not exists (select null
 11                    from test b
 12                    where b.testprocedure = a.testprocedure
 13                    group by b.testprocedure
 14                    having sum(b.charge) = 0
 15                       and sum(b.billcount) = 0
 16                   );

TESTPROC ACT  BILLCOUNT     CHARGE
-------- --- ---------- ----------
109.0200 NEW          1      83,33
300.0500 NEW          1          0
310.5200 ADD          1      66,67

SQL>
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I had an issue getting the HAVING code the way I needed it, but after seeing the way you layed it out, this works perfect. Thank you!